# Can a Java varargs be null?

Tags: java, variadic-functions, null-check

I found myself checking for this and asking if it's necessary. I have code like this:

```
public Object myMethod(Object... many) {
  if (many == null || many.length == 0)
    return this;
  for (Object one : many)
    doSomethingWith(one);
  return that;
}
```

But then I wondered... Am I being too cautious? **Do I have to check if `many == null`? Is that ever possible in any current Java version?** If so, how? If not, I'll probably keep checking, just for futureproofing in case Oracle decides it can be null one day.

Comment: @sdotdi what would I try? Would `myMethod(null)` not pass it an array like `new Object[]{null}`?

Comment: As a side note, the code you have here is a code smell. Passing in a varargs object array means that your method can accept anything. I can imagine specific situations where this might be useful, but I would say that this is generally something to avoid.

Comment: http://ideone.com/wP9AFE

Comment: As IDEA suggests, `null` can be explicitly passed to varargs methods with cast - `(Object[]) null`, so yes, passing `null` is possible in Java and your check makes sense

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I tried it with `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0 on Linux 3.5.0-21-generic`

Using `myMethod(null)` doesn't pass `new Object[]{null}`, it passes `null`. [Arrays are objects in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3) and therefore `null` is valid for the type `Object[]`.

Your nullcheck is, therefore, not overly cautious.